# using capitalize on a collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, capitalize

If this has been answered before I cannot find it.

I have the following:

```
= f.collection_select :sex_id, @sexes, :id, :name
```

and this in the controller:

```
@sexes = Sex.all
```

the sexes are all stored in lowercase, like this:

```
id|name
 1|steer
 2|heifer
 3|holstein
```

I need them to output with Capital First letters:

```
Steer
Heifer
Holstein
```

I tried:

```
= f.collection_select :sex_id, @sexes, :id, :name.capitalize
= f.collection_select :sex_id, @sexes, 'id', 'name'.capitalize
```

but they do not work, and I didn't really expect them to, but had to try them before posting this.

Comment: The Wisconsinite in me asks why you're mixing two sexes with a breed. The data's no good! ;-)

Comment: My company is weird like that, but it is cool to work in an industry where you can have "animal sex" in a database and nobody thinks you've lost it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collection_select` calls a method on each object to get the text for the option value. You can add a new method in the model to get the right value:

```
def name_for_select
  name.capitalize
end
```

then in the view:

```
= f.collection_select :sex_id, @sexes, :id, :name_for_select
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your initial attempt is not working is that you're attempting to capitalize a symbol or a string that represents the field name and not the actual variable.

You could do something like this and then the data would be capitalized before it's sent to the view.

```
@sexes = Sex.all    
@sexes = @sexes.each{|sex| sex.name.capitalize}
```

or

```
@sexes = Sex.all.each{|sex| sex.name.capitalize}
```

Comment: I should have thought of this...  Although, the other solution is much cleaner.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, after I saw the other answer i kicked myself a bit. Too easy :P

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to do this in RoR4 would be to use the [humanize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) method. So, your view code would look like this:

```
= f.collection_select :sex_id, @sexes, :id, :humanize
```

No need for any extra methods!